# Cancel task in auth case

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created task for creating user, and then I want to cancel the task or remove listener. How can I do it ?

```
 Task authTask = mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditText.toString(), passwordEditText.toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            //todo
        }
    });
```

com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task doesn't have api for it. 
Why ?

Comment: As far as I know a task once started cannot be cancelled. You'll have to wait for it to complete and then undo the action (e.g. delete the user that you created). There is also no way to remove a listener that I know of. Btw: your questions sounds very much like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You'll probably get better answers if you explain what you're trying to accomplish and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I want to cancel task or somthing like this in the following simple case:  1) Try to create  firebase user in fragment. If user click back or exite app I want to cancel task in onDestroyView method of fragment for example.  I know that firebase has Api for the case but the api only for activity. (see good blog about it - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-2.html)